# Html2Canvas.js 'getElementsByTagName' error in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I am using html2canvas.js to convert html elements to images and then creating a PDF of those images to print.

I have used html2canvas.js version 0.4.1 and 0.5.0 and I have no problems in IE, but Chrome and Firefox always throw "**element.getElementsByTagname is not a function".**

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be `getElementsByTagName`, not `getElementsByTagname`.